# Creating a new relation in neo4j takes to long. (over 488000 ms)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What could be the reason for this cypher query to take over 488000 ms?

```
MATCH (u:User {objectId: 'idUusera'}) 
MATCH (a:Action {objectId: 'idActiona'}) 
MERGE (u)-[r:CREATED]->(a)
```

The database contains tens of thousands of actions but this happens only for some users. There is already an index on User.objectId and Action.objectId

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible explanation.

The `MERGE` clause needs to verify that the relationship does not already exist. Therefore, it needs to scan *all* the `CREATED` relationships of either `u` or `a`. In your DB, it is probably the case that on average a `User` has fewer such relationships than an `Action`. Therefore, the Cypher planner has decided to scan all outgoing `CREATED` relationships of `u` to verify that `a` is not on the other side.

Some `User` nodes, however, may have an enormous number of outgoing `CREATED` relationships. For such users, the scan could take a very long time.